# Toad: how to loop a resultset of select

Tags: sql, select, foreach, sqlplus, toad

I'm using Toad and there is a table named `MyTable`, it has a column named `INFO`:
**INFO**
abcd
efgh
ijkl

What I need is to take the elements of `INFO` one by one and do tasks. So I think I need something like below:

```
foreach (select INFO from MyTable)
    print
end
```

I tried to Google and it seems that I should use CURSOR. So I tried like this:

```
DEF msg varchar2(15);

cursor cr is
    select info from mytable;

begin
  OPEN cr;
  loop
    FETCH cr into msg;
    exit when cr%NOTFOUND;
    -- do job
  end loop;
  CLOSE cr;
end;
```

But I got an error:

> cursor cr is
>   Error at line 3
>   ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
>   Script Terminated on line 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearly you want to execute a `PL/SQL` block, but `DEF` is not a part of PL/SQL.
Try to execute following block:

```
declare
msg varchar2(15);
cursor cr is
    select info from mytable;
begin
  OPEN cr;
  loop
    FETCH cr into msg;
    exit when cr%NOTFOUND;
    -- do job
  end loop;
  CLOSE cr;
end;
```

You can also do the same using [cursor for loop statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/static.htm#LNPLS553)

```
begin
  for rec in (
    select info from mytable
  ) loop
      -- do job (you can reference info by using rec.info )
  end loop;
end;
```